# How to integrate 2 factor authentication in my Xamarin.Forms project?

Tags: authentication, xamarin

I am new at Xamarin mobile app development. I want to integrate 2 factor authentication in my Xamarin.Forms project. But I don't know how to do it. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Your question is too broad, I think you should at least specify which technology you want to use to perform two-factors authentication.

Comment: Hi there, I have already mentioned to use in Xamarin.Forms that is Xamarin cross platform for mobile development. I have found some example of 2 factor authentication in asp.net mvc but didn't find for Xamarin.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest the following solution:

- Azure Active Directory as directory and multi-factor authentication service. You can use Azure AD accounts for access or integrate Azure AD with corporate Active Directory domain with Active Directory Federation Services. Here you get account management and multi-factor infrastructure (phone registration, call/SMS service and policies)
- [Active Directory Authentication Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries) (ADAL) to use inside Xamarin Forms app.
- Using Dependency Service in Xamarin.Forms app to define authentication interface like:

  ```
  public interface IAuthenticator
  {
    Task<AuthenticationResult> Authenticate(string authority, string resource, string clientId, string returnUri);
  }
  ```
- Provide implementation for every platform ([here is all details](https://blog.xamarin.com/put-adal-xamarin-forms/)) with assembly Dependency metadata attribute:

  ```
  [assembly: Dependency(typeof(MFATestPCL.Droid.Helper.Authenticator))]
  namespace MFATestPCL.Droid.Helper
  ```
- Make a call from the shared code:

  ```
  var auth = DependencyService.Get<IAuthenticator>();
  authResult = await auth.Authenticate(authority, graphResourceUri, clientId, returnUri);
  ```

Here is full GitHub [sample Xamarin app repo with step-by-step guide of configuring Azure AD](https://github.com/rzdebskiy/XamarinFormsMFASample) – iOS, Android and Windows 10 UWP implementations provided.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I know that can be easily integrated in Xamarin is Azure Active Directory B2C. 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/active-directory-b2c/

It's practically customer identity and access management portal that comes with identity management (scalability, sign in, sign up, password reset, 2FA, etc.)